# root frame not responding in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Willing to develop a media player which will show 'lyrics', guitar and piano code when a song is played, but getting no idea how to begin with. I have started with the following code, which is giving me 'filedialog not defined' error when add_play_list button is pressed for the fist time, on second run this error disappears. Code can play songs in the folder but the root frame window is 'not responding' until all songs are played. How can I solve these problems? How can I add lyrics and guitar code in labels? Your guidance will help. Thanks.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import mutagen
import pygame

root= Tk()
root.title("AVPlayer")
root.geometry("500x250")

top_frame= Frame(root, bg='red')
top_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

playlist= Listbox(top_frame, relief='flat', 
font=("Arial",8),fg='white', bg='red')  
playlist.pack( fill=BOTH, expand=True, 
padx=10, pady=10)  

vscroll=Scrollbar(playlist)
vscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
vscroll.config(command=playlist.yview)
playlist.config(yscrollcommand=vscroll.set)


midl_frame=Frame(root, bg="red", height=50)
midl_frame.pack(fill=BOTH)  

add_play_list= Button(midl_frame,text="+", 
bg='red', font=('Arial', 15), 
relief='flat', borderwidth=2, fg='white', 
command=playlistitems)  
add_play_list.pack(padx=10, side=LEFT)

nextbtn=Button(midl_frame, text='>|',font= 
('Arial',15),bg='red',fg='white', 
relief='flat',borderwidth=2)  
nextbtn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10)

prvsbtn=Button(midl_frame, text='|<',font= 
('Arial',15),bg='red',fg='white', 
relief='flat',borderwidth=2)  
prvsbtn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10)

pausebtn=Button(midl_frame, text='||', 
bg='red', font=('Arial',15), relief='flat', 
borderwidth=2, fg='white')  
pausebtn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10)

playbtn= Button(midl_frame,text='>', 
bg='red', font=('Arial',15), relief='flat', 
borderwidth=2, fg='white', 
command=playaudio)  
playbtn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10)

songlist=[]

def playlistitems(event):
    global flpath    
    flpath= filedialog.askdirectory()

    for i in os.listdir(flpath):
        if i.endswith(".mp3"):
        title= 
       mutagen.File(os.path.join(flpath,i))
        playlist.insert(END,title['TIT2'][0])
        songlist.append(i)


def playaudio(event):
    for x in songlist:
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load
        (os.path.join(flpath,x))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

       while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
           pygame.time.Clock().tick(100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your import should be `from tkinter import filedialog`.

Comment: To solve the not responding problem, you need to look up how to play file "asynchronously". You can't use blocking code like that while loop in a GUI program.

Comment: You may be better off with a more beginner oriented forum such as learnpython.reddit.com